# Angular translation in *ngFor

Tags: angular, internationalization, translate

I m currently working on translations on the angular weather App with `@angular-devkit/core 10.0.8`.
In my form component, I listed a set of method of localization of the city if one day I wanted to implement some additional features like adding the possibility to enter the GPS tool localization

```
  allMethods = [
    { id: 1, name: 'City', inputs: ['Name of city'] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Geographic', inputs: ['latitude of city', 'longitude of the city'] },
  ];
```

That's in the inputComponent.ts
Here is what i have done in the template html view (i only put the interesting part of the template) :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let method of methods">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="City" id="{{method.name}}" [value]="method.name"
                    (click)="changeMethod($event)" [checked]="method.name == 'City'">
                <label [for]="method.name">
                    {{method.name}}
                </label>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Results of an interactive form:

[form with name input selection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO5ay.png)

[form with latitude/longitude image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8t0L.png)

Now what I want to do is translate the "city" and "geographic" in the labels at the right. What I have already tried is to use i18n select method: didn't work, I tried to use pipe translate like this {{method.name |translate}} with the translate pipe using `@ngx-translate/core`. Actually that worked but I'm not really satisfied with how I implemented it and I would prefer to not use ngx translate. Is it possible to do without it and how?
Thanks for your help.
Ps: I read some post talking about it but there are outdated